# How are numerals written in Arabic?

Tags: written-language, arabic, numbers, numerals

How are multi-digit numbers written in Arabic?

For example, if someone wanted to write 123, would they write "321" from the right or in some other way?

Comment: [Related](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/how-are-line-breaks-handled-in-bidirectional-messages-containing-both-english-an)

Comment: I know that many Germans write 2-digit numbers, e.g. 46, starting with the last digit, that is with 6 in my example, just the way they are pronounced in German, 'sechsundvierzig', that is '6 and 40'.

Comment: Are you asking how the numbers look in the writing, or in which order they are drawn on paper?

Comment: Also, the order you type it might not match the order you handwrite it. At least in the built-in keyboard in translate.google.com, if you type in the equivalent of "AL 123" the rightmost character will be alif and the leftmost character will be the one.

Answer (score 5):

No, he will write the digits from left to right (the opposite of the direction of writing words) as: 123 or ۱۲۳.

Comment: @Medi1Saif. I think you mean: first hundreds (1), then units (3), then tens (2). مائة وثلاثة وعشرون

Comment: Ups you are right.